# efficient parallel(vector) matrix-times matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Does anyone know how to do array matrix multiplication in matlab? i.e. I have two 3 dimensional arrays consisting of sets of matrices in the first 2 dimensions and I would like to multiply each matrix in the first array with the corresponding one in the second array.  So, i.e. if

```
A=randn(3,3);
B=cat(3,A,A);
```

I would like [[operation]] such that

```
B[[operation]]B = cat(3,A*A, A*A)
```

done in efficient vector form.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Like this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24260-multiple-same-size-linear-solver ?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand the requirements, but what is wrong with: `C = A*A` followed by `cat(3,C,C)`

Answer (score 1):

I have used [MULTIPROD](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8773-multiple-matrix-multiplications-with-array-expansion-enabled) from the Mathworks FileExchange for N-D array multiplication before. It is basically an extension of `bsxfun` to N-D arrays, and works quite nicely (and **fast**) - although the interface is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: Amazing -- thank you!  I knew someone must have thought of this before!